# Data.table is not returned visibly after applying ':='

Tags: r, data.table

Given a function

```
testf <- function(dt){

  dt[, t := seq(1:nrow(dt))]
  return(dt)

}
```

and the data.table:

```
dt <- data.table(a=1, b=2)
```

when applying the function on this data.table and not assigning the output to a variable there is for some reason I don't understand no visible output generated.

```
testf(dt)
#nothing
```

hoewever, when take the same function but with a print function before it does:

```
    testf <- function(dt){

      dt[, t := seq(1:nrow(dt))]
      print(dt)
      return(dt)

    }

testd(dt)
   a b t
1: 1 2 1
   a b t
1: 1 2 1
```

When assigning the Output to a variable the output is however actually stored in that variable, no matter whether a print() function is called within the function or not:

```
t <- testf(dt)
View(t)
#Output visible
```

Can anybody explain me what is going wrong here?

Comment: You can use `copy()`: `testf <- function(dt){ dt[, t := seq(1:nrow(dt))];  copy(dt) }`

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#why-do-i-have-to-type-dt-sometimes-twice-after-using-to-print-the-result-to-console

Comment: I really hope it is not a real function though. No sense running `seq` over `:`. Also, data.table has the `.I` operator too. Regarding your issue, it is a known thing regarding `\`:=\`` and functions, I really hope you've searched before posting

Comment: Thank you. No real function, just for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to specify the `[]` after the assignment

```
testf <- function(dt){

  dt[, t := seq(1:nrow(dt))][]

}
testf(dt)
#  a b t
#1: 1 2 1
```

Comment: oh thank you! could you maybe explain in which general cases this is necessary? would not have realized

Comment: @yasel if you need to return the output into the console, otherwise,w hen you assign it to a object, the value would be there